# Printing boost::array<> to stdout

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a `boost::array` declared as below

```
typedef boost::array<unsigned char, 4096> m_array_type;
m_array_type m_recv_buf;
```

I want to output `m_recv_buf` to `stdout`.

`std::cout << m_recv_buf << std::endl;`

doesn't seem to work? How do I print this to `stdout`

Comment: C++ containers don't usually have standard ways to output them. What would you expect the output to be anyway?

Comment: @Cubic - I would like the contents of the array to be printed to the screen.

Comment: But how? This is in no way well defined. Do you want a pretty print of the array? Do you want to treat it like a string? I don't know what you want from your description.

Comment: @Cubic - I want to treat it like a string. But I aslo want to provide a len parameter and I want to print from beginning to that len.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ostream.write](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write):

```
std::cout.write(&m_recv_buf[0], len);
```

Also, you specified the C++11 tag. Consider using std::array, which is now standard.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print your `m_array_type` as a string, you'll need the string to properly end with a null terminator.  So this approach creates a `std::string` type, explicitly sending the length to the `std::string` constructor.

```
std::cout << std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(m_recv_buf.data()), m_recv_buf.size()) << std::endl;
```

I think this way would be clear to others who have to use your code.  But the previous answer would be way better if `m_array_type` ever changes it's type.